# Why is my filesystem size larger than the partition size. (df vs fdisk)

Tags: filesystem, btrfs, fdisk, df, du

So...
I get that `fdisk` lists partition sizes, and `df` lists filesystem sizes, and that filesystem may use a portion of the partition and disagree on the size, but why would `df` list filesystem sizes that are *larger* that the partition sizes?

[image]

`df:    /dev/sda6 200G`

`fdisk: /dev/sda5 7.8G`

Wut?

Comment: sda6 seems to be mounted in two different places, / and /home -- that probably confuses things.

Comment: Perhaps related to btrfs? (which I don't have a full understanding of).

Comment: fdisk seems to be wrong: the total size of the disk is displayed as 12 GiB, which seems very small for nowadays disks. The sector size of 512 bytes seems strange: nowadays we see often 4096 bytes or sometimes more. Perhaps you can try other programs like parted or cfdisk.